# How to set EasyMock expectations after @Autowired injection?

Tags: spring, testing, jaxb, spring-ws, easymock

I'm trying to get to grips with EasyMock in order to run some server side integration tests on a spring-ws web service. I have a DAO which I want to mock for my integration testing, I've managed to autowire it successfully, but I can't figure out how to set the expectations post autowire.

I have the following in my spring context xml:

```
<bean id="accountServiceDao" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.xxx.account.dao.AccountServiceDao" />
</bean> 

<bean id="notMockedDao" class="com.xxx.account.dao.AccountServiceDaoImpl"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.account" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:accountDetailService_test.properties" />

<sws:annotation-driven />

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/db_schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/test_data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

My dummy test is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext_test.xml" })
public class AccountDetailServiceMockIntergrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

    @Before
    public void createClient() {

        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);

        /* Set the expectations for the autowired mock dao here */

    }

    @Test
    public void customerEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Source requestPayload = new StringSource(TestData.requestXML);

        Source responsePayload = new StringSource(TestData.responseXML);

        mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload)).andExpect(
                payload(responsePayload));
    }
}
```

The endpoint which is hit is below:

```
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@PayloadRoot(localPart = "AccountSearchRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload
AccountSearchResponse getAccountDetails(
        @RequestPayload AccountSearchRequest request) {
    logger.info("Received request | debtornum - " + request.getDebtornum());

    AccountSearchResponse accountSearchResponse = objectFactory.createAccountSearchResponse();
    AccountDetailsType accountDetails = accountService.getAccountDetails(request.getDebtornum());

    accountSearchResponse.setAccountDetails(accountDetails);

    logger.info("Returned response | status - " + accountSearchResponse.getAccountDetails().getDebtorStatus().value());

    return accountSearchResponse;
}
```

And here's the service class which contains the DAO which is being mocked

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    //Autowired on a setter
    private AccountServiceDao accountServiceDao;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public AccountDetailsType getAccountDetails(BigInteger accountNumber) {

........................
```

Via debug I can see that the mock DAO is getting injected correctly, but I don't know how to set the behavior on the mock object.

For my unit tests I was able to do the following:

```
    accountDao = EasyMock.createMock(AccountServiceDao.class);

    EasyMock.expect(accountDao.checkAccountExists(new BigInteger("12345678"))).andReturn(new Account(new BigInteger("12345678"),"Y",1,0,0,0,"ROI","ROI","DO","10012054082","POST","DD","John Doe","a@a.com","123456"));

    EasyMock.replay(accountDao);

    testSvc.setAccountServiceDao(accountDao);
```

I'm not sure how to do the same configuration when the mock is autowired via spring xml config. I'm probably missing something obvious or misunderstanding EasyMock, but any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From your Context file and the look of your dummy test, you don't seem to have a bean for the `ApplicationContext` object you're injecting. 
If you want a mock `AccountServiceDao` in your test, then autowire that into the test.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for replying. The applicationContext is being autowired based on the applicationContext_test.xml config. I have two beans explicitly defined in this XML, one for the mock DAO and another for a DAO which uses an in memory DB. The autowiring of the mock isn't a problem, I can see that it has been injected via debug. However, I don't know how to configure the behavior of the mock in this type of setup. Normally, I'd define the mock object explicitly in my test, configure it, and the use a set method. When you define the mock in XML and autowire it, where do you configure it?

Comment: If the object you want to configure (set expectations on) is being injected correctly and is an EasyMock mock, then you would just add you expectations as normal and set the mock on other objects as normal (either in a test or in an @Before method). The only difference here is that Spring has essentially made the `EasyMock.createMock()` call for you. Another point: I'm not entirely sure why, but I've always been told to always use `EasyMock.reset()` on mock objects that Spring has injected in case Spring has called any methods on the mock before it makes it to the test class

Comment: Thanks Dan, the reset stuff is probably verging on the cargo cult.
I got it working with 

`AccountServiceDao svcDao = (AccountServiceDao)applicationContext.getBean("accountServiceDao");`

and then setting the expectations on `svcDao`. I have a bit of mental block when it comes to `.getBean()`. I never feel quite right using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Dan's comment above, I've set my expectations as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext_test.xml" })
public class AccountDetailServiceMockIntergrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

    @Before
    public void createClient() {

        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);

        //get the mocked bean from the applicationContext
        AccountServiceDao svcDao = (AccountServiceDao)applicationContext.getBean("accountServiceDao");

        //reset just in case
        EasyMock.reset();

        //set expectations on the mock
        EasyMock.expect(svcDao.checkAccountExists(new BigInteger("12345678"))).andReturn(new Account(new BigInteger("12345678"),"Y",1,0,0,0,"ROI","ROI","DO","10012054082","POST","DD","John Doe","a@a.com","123456"));

        EasyMock.replay(svcDao);
    }

    @Test
    public void customerEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Source requestPayload = new StringSource(TestData.requestXML);

        Source responsePayload = new StringSource(TestData.responseXML);

        mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload)).andExpect(
                payload(responsePayload));
    }
}
```

Works fine.